# Layout xml is not working in smaller devices

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I made an Android app for which i wrote the following xml code .It's showing up properly in big devices but not showing in smaller devices such as galaxy y.So i want to make my 
code dynamic so that it can be displayed in all devices.

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/ivReturnedPic"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="250dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:src="@drawable/back" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/ibtakePic"
    android:layout_width="125dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:text="click to snap" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvDisplay"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:background="#EEEEEE"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="Fool Around By  Clicking Test"
    android:textColor="#0000ff"
    android:textSize="35dp" />
<Button
    android:id="@+id/test"
    android:layout_width="344dp"
    android:layout_height="101dp"
    android:text="test" />
```

Comment: what is the problem you are facing?

Comment: its not showing up properly in smaller devices , i mean last part of code , test button can't be viewed up @Gogu

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html You should use layout_width="match_parent" instead of 344 dp. Width for phones is usually 320dp.

Comment: @Gogu :there is no change even after doing the change u told

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Test button is not shown as remaining items in the view are taking up the whole screen. You should use ScrollView so that the screen becomes scrollable and handle varying screen sizes.

```
    <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

  <LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
  </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: where i have to keep the buttons and text view and image view , inside the linear layout ? @Gogu